# Set Attribute of item in HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, dom, htmlcollection

Skip to bottom to see questions:

I'm having a hell of a time with the htmlCollections that are being tossed back to me from

```
document.getElementById("Id")
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")
```

Now, I always thought that byClassName and TagName were the only ones that returned a HTML collection, but for some reason, this code is logging an htmlCollection on the second line. No good

```
var findPos = function(el) {
  console.log(el)
  var curleft = curtop = 0;
  if (el.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curleft += el.offsetLeft;
      curtop += el.offsetTop;
    } while (el = el.offsetParent);
    el.setAttribute("data-off-top", curtop);
  };
}

var myElement = document.getElementById("myId");
findPos(myElement);
```

does the exact same thing and I have no idea why.

before, I had the last 2 lines as this, and I was getting an HTMLCollection which is not helpful as readonly.

```
var affixElements = document.getElementsByClassName("affixMe");
for (var i = 0; i < affixElements.length; i++) {
  var thisOne = affixElements.item(i);
  findPos(thisOne);
};
```

I have two questions:

1) why would getElementById return a htmlCollection?

I have already checked the document and there is nothing else with a id="myId"

2) how can I set Attributes in individual items of the HTML collection for say setting the data attribute for an offset function?

Comment: `getElementById` doesn't return an `HTMLCollection`, your observation must be wrong. *"ow can I set Attributes in individual items of the HTML collection"* Simple access the element with bracket notation or `.item()`, as you are already doing, and call `setAttribute` on the element.